# Modular form of Congruence Subgroup: Checking holomorphicity at cusps after Hecke operator

Tags: modular-forms

Let's say I have a modular form $f \in M_{k}^{!}(\Gamma_{0}(N))$ which is holomorphic at the cusps *except* $\infty$, and I apply the Hecke operator $T_{k}(p)$ at a prime $p$ not dividing $N$ to get the summation

$$p^{\frac{k}{2} -1}\left( \sum_{j=0}^{p-1} f \mid_{k} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & j \\ 0 & p \end{pmatrix} + f \mid_{k} \begin{pmatrix} p & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right).$$

I want to then say this new summation is holomorphic at the cusps. There's a trick I saw in a paper: let $r \in \mathbb{Q}$ be a cusp of $\Gamma_{0}(N)$ that is *not* equivalent to $\infty$, and let $\gamma = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}) \setminus \Gamma_{0}(N)$ with $\gamma \infty = r$. A "standard argument" shows that

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & j \\ 0 & p \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{a + cj}{\lambda} & * \\ \frac{cp}{\lambda} & * \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & * \\ 0 & \frac{p}{\lambda} \end{pmatrix}$$

(which I believe to be true, so I'll take that for granted for now). The first matrix on the right is in the full modular group and *not* in $\Gamma_{0}(N)$. The author of the paper then claims that each summand on $j$ above is now holomorphic at the cusps. Why is this?

[The same trick is used for the last summand $f \mid_{k} \begin{pmatrix} p & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.]

Comment: Can you state precisely "those each summands corresponding to $f|_k$ above". The weight $k$ Hecke operators act as $T_p \sum_n a_n e^{2i \pi nz} = p^{k-1} \sum_n a_n e^{2i \pi pnz}+ \sum_n a_{pn} e^{2i \pi nz}$ when there are negative coefficients too

Comment: @reuns Of course, let me edit it!